# how to use TraversalSpec to track new task state change

Tags: python, vsphere, pyvmomi

I'm using pyVmomi, I create a TraversalSpec to recurse through the objects I want to monitor with the property collector.

I want to know how to set the TraversalSpec and property collector to monitor the new task. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

get a solution without TraversalSpec:

```
taskFilterSpec = vim.TaskFilterSpec()
task_manager = si.content.taskManager.CreateCollectorForTasks(filter=taskFilterSpec)
pc = si.content.propertyCollector

filterSpec = vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.FilterSpec()

objSpecs = []
objSpec = vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.ObjectSpec(obj=task_manager)
objSpecs.append(objSpec)
filterSpec.objectSet = objSpecs

propSet = []
motype = type(task_manager)
propSpec = vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.PropertySpec(type=motype, all=True)
propSet.append(propSpec)
filterSpec.propSet = propSet

pcFilter = pc.CreateFilter(filterSpec, True)
```

But I still want to know how to deal it with TraversalSpec..